# What is the difference between these two pieces of Python code?

Tags: python, python-2.7

What is the difference between these two pieces of code? The first one returns a list of tokens as expected but the second piece of code seems to just return a list with 1 item.

**Variables**

```
sentences = load_parsed_example_sentences() # list of sentences
# sentences are a list of BasicTokens
# BasicTokens are single words
aspects = ["plot"]
```

**Code Sample 1:**

```
for aspect in aspects:
    for sentence in sentences:
        aspect_tokens = sentence.get_query_tokens(aspect)
        print aspect_tokens[0]
```

**Code Sample 2:**

```
aspect_tokens = [aspect_token for aspect in aspects for sentence in sentences for aspect_token in sentence.get_query_tokens(aspect)]
print aspect_tokens[0]
```

Are these two not the same?

Comment: Could you provide a "working" code? Appropriate variables `aspects` and `sentences` for example.

Comment: Aren't you after `[sentence.get_query_tokens(aspect)[0] for aspect in aspects for sentence in sentences]` to make this the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both code segments are different.

In the first one, you are calling the `sentence.get_query_tokens(aspect)` and printing the first instance of the aspect token obtained.

In the second one, you are using the list builder construct to build an array of aspect tokens and printing out the first set of tokens.

Answer (score 1):

Your first sample prints once per each `sentence` per each `aspect`, so you'll get a total of `len(aspects) * len(sentences)` prints (assuming `aspects` and `sentences` are lists).  Your second sample only has one `print`, so it will only print one element.

Do you expect `aspect_tokens` to be the same after each sample executes?  Because they won't be.  The first sample reassigns `aspect_tokens` in each iteration, so after the loops execute, `aspect_tokens` will be equal to the last computed value, specifically, `sentences[-1].get_query_tokens(aspects[-1])`.

I'm deciphering what you're after might be the following:

#### Code Sample 1

```
aspect_tokens = []
for aspect in aspects:
    for sentence in sentences:
        all_aspect_tokens.append(sentence.get_query_tokens(aspect)[0])
```

#### Code Sample 2

```
aspect_tokens = [sentence.get_query_tokens(aspect)[0] for sentence in sentences for aspect in aspects]
```

These two samples will result in identical `aspect_tokens` lists.

Answer (score 0):

```
aspect_tokens = [sentence.get_query_tokens(aspect)[0] for aspect in aspects for sentence in sentences]
print aspect_tokens
```

Answer (score 0):

They're not equivalent.
The first iterates over `aspects` and `sentences`, and creates a list of tokens at each step. Then it prints the first token in the list. But it does that once for each step.
The second creates a list, into which it puts each list that `get__query_tokens` produces. Then it prints a single set of token once, at the end.
I'm generally a big fan of list comprehensions, but I'd argue that in this case they should not be used because it's making the code harder to read.